# Как узнать есть ли индекс в QList?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Узнать есть ли значение 3 функции, а есть ли индекс в `QList<int>` не понятно

```
 QList<int> ppc;
 ppc[0]=100;
 ppc[1]=200;
 ppc[2]=300;
 ppc[3]=400;
 int res = ppc.at(4);
```

Конечно вылазит окно ошибки, а как узнать есть ли ключ в списке не понятно, должна же быть там функция.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Понятие ключа относится к словарям (`dict`, `map`), а у списком, массивов и множеств (`list`, `array`, `set`) доступ к элементам осуществляется через индекс, который начинается от `0 до <размер - 1>` или от `1 до размер`.

Поэтому, чтобы проверить наличие индекса, нужно обратиться к размеру и сравнить размер с индексом.

У `QList` для проверки размера есть аж 3 идентичных функции: `count`, `size` и `length`.

Для вашего примера нужно добавить проверку:

```
int index = 4;

// Для индексации от 0 до n - 1
// А для индексации от 0 до n, проверка изменится на: index <= ppc.size()
if (index < ppc.size()) {
    int res = ppc.at(index); // или ppc[index]
}
```

---

`QList` при неправильном индексе исключение не кидает (так исторически сложилось в `Qt`), но, например, в `java` есть [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), а у python это [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

Тогда, вместо проверки можно ловить исключение, например тогда код с проверкой изменился бы на что-то такое:

```
int index = 4;

try {
    int res = ppc.at(index);

} catch (IndexError) {
    // ignore
}
```

Comment: Спс. Тоже про это подумал. Хотя странно почему бы не сделать такую функцию, по моему гораздо логичней чем делать 3 одинаковые функции.

Comment: @MadokaMagica, во-первых, в с++ неперехваченные исключения в конструкторах могут вести к утечке памяти, а в деструкторах к вызову `std::termiante`. Во-вторых, проверки границ диапазона дают дополнительные расходы, которые нужны далеко не всегда, поэтому разумнее было оставить их на совести пользователя библиотеки.

Comment: добавлю, что за примерами исключений не обязательно идти к java'е или питону... stl'евские контейнеры вроде `std::vector`'а их тоже кидают в `at()`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо за уточнение :)